# Cannot remote connected to digitalocean droplet - not permited password

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I can not connect to my droplet on digital ocean. I create it, work with it, copy and launch my project on the server and all this I do from local laptop, without any problem. But after a while, the server not connected by 'ssh'. I can join into console from digitalocean site and all well work.

[image]

But in remote, by ssh I get timeout connecting error every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

The problem is that I created an easy password for the server. 
When I did create strong password the issue not repeats.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons behind this, Maybe you misconfigured your firewall and you are blocking incoming ssh connections to your droplet.
Another reason could be that your ssh server is down, or the you changed the default ssh port.

Comment: There is no problem on the local computer because I can request other servers. SSH port I do not change

Answer (score 0):

The problem sometimes might be not enabling port 22.

Once you are logged in to your web console, us this command

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```